# PHP UTF-8 encoding problem of U+009A

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have problems displaying the Unicode character of U+009A.

It should look like "š", but instead looks like a rectangular block with the numbers 009A inside.

Converting it to the entity "&#x9A;" displays the character correctly, but I don't want to store entities in the database.

The encoding of the webpage is in UTF-8.

The character is URL-encoded as "%C2%9A".

Reproduce:
 # php -E 'echo urldecode("%C2%9A");' > /tmp/test ; less /tmp/test

This gives me <U+009A> in less or <9A> in vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unicode character "š" is U+0161, not U+009A

I suspect that it's 0x9A in another character set.

The box with 009A is usually shown when you don't have a font installed with that character.

Comment: Maybe that makes more sense. The content was most likely copied from Word, with all the strange things coming with that...

This gives me what I need:
html_entity_decode("&#x0161;", ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");

 But, there are more of these characters, so I would need a mapping or a way to convert between them

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Gumbo. The following code solved my problem (somehow I needed the utf8_decode first, but I guess the XML feed was UTF-8 encoded as well): $_output = utf8_decode($_output); $_output = mb_convert_encoding($_output, 'UTF-8', 'windows-1252');

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using UTF-8 as your input encoding, then you can simply use the plain `š`. Or you could use the hexadecimal representation `"\xC2\x9A"` (in double quotes) that’s independent from the input encoding. Or `utf8_encode("\x9A")` since the first 256 characters of Unicode and ISO 8859-1 are identical.

Comment: This gives me the same result as before:
 # php -E 'echo utf8_encode("\x9A"); echo "\n";' > /tmp/test ; less /tmp/test

Answer (score 0):

If I do a hexdump of the output of `echo urldecode("%C2%9A");` I get `c2 9a`, which is the correct UTF-8 encoding for character 0x9a.

You get that same encoding from the output of `utf8_encode("\x9A")`

When I try to view Unicode char 0x9a, I get a square box too - suspect it's not the char you think it should be (Aha: as Azquelt has posted, unicode character "š" is U+0161, not U+009A)

Comment: I get "9ac2", but I guess that has to do with big/little endian?
I have tested this on Ubuntu i686 and on RedHat4 i686.

$ php -E 'echo urldecode("%C2%9A");' > /tmp/test ; od -t x2 /tmp/test

0000000 9ac2

0000002

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter have utf-8 character input data save issue in some hosting servers like Etisalat. system/core/Utf8.php have function to detect illegal char in input data(post/get). In some cases utf-8 char is consider as illegal and save function will fail. For avoid data saving issue do the following in clean_string() function of Utf8.php at line 85.

$str = !mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', TRUE) ? utf8_encode($str) : $str;

$str = @iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $str);